# d3 donut/pie chart - drawing a line between arcs

Tags: d3.js, charts, pie-chart, donut-chart

can't figure to find the endpoint of the arc to draw a line from (0,0) to the arc's endpoint..image attached

[image]

I could find the centroid of the arc and draw a line but here I want to pull a line to end of arc so that I can extend that line to the left /right side (and then append the circle at line's endpoint)...could't find any such solution over whole google. Any help will be appreciated. Just a hint will do.

Comment: post the work you have done so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a data array to the [pie generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_pie), it returns an array of objects with the following properties:

- `data` - the input datum; the corresponding element in the input data array.
- `value` - the numeric value of the arc.
- `index` - the zero-based sorted index of the arc.
- `startAngle` - the start angle of the arc.
- `endAngle` - the end angle of the arc.
- `padAngle` - the pad angle of the arc.

From these, you can use `startAngle` or `endAngle` to draw your lines, since they hold the arcs' starting points (and endpoints).

But there is a catch: unlike the regular trigonometric representation, D3 pie generator puts the `0` angle at 12 o'clock:

> The angular units are arbitrary, but if you plan to use the pie generator in conjunction with an arc generator, you should specify angles in radians, with 0 at -y (12 o’clock) and positive angles proceeding clockwise.

Therefore, we have to subtract `Math.PI/2` to get the correct angles.

In the following demo, the coordinates are calculates using sine and cosine:

```
.attr("y2", function(d) {
    return Math.sin(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) * (outerRadius)
})
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return Math.cos(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) * (outerRadius)
})
```

Check the demo:

```js
var data = [10, ,12, 50, 15, 20, 40, 6, 32, 17];

var width = 500,
  height = 400,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null);

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 100)
  .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc);

var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return Math.sin(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) * (radius - 50)
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return Math.cos(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) * (radius - 50)
  })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you apply pie layout to your dataset by doing

```
var pieData = myPieLayout(myDataset)
```

inside pieData you will find, for each element of your dataset, two properties called startAngle and endAngle. Using that, you can find the position of the point you want, from the center of the pie by iterating through pieData elements and doing

```
var x = Math.cos(d.endAngle)*radius
var y = Math.sin(d.endAngle)*radius
```